# Ubuntu 12.04 stuck on "checking for running unattended upgrades" message while restarting

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer, my hard disk is shared by another thin client terminal. 
When I try to shut-down or restart my computer I get a black screen with the words `halted` and nothing else happens.

This is the screen I get:

[image: Error Message]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It belongs on [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once faced this problem with Ubuntu 12.04 on a HP x360 and I fixed the problem by adding `acpi=noirq` to the kernel arguments.

To do this you'll first you'll need to go open the `/etc/default/grub` file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then you'll need to set the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

Save your file using:

```
ctrl + o
```

Then exit nano using:

```
ctrl + x
```

You must then update grub like this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Good luck and all the best.

Comment: Thank you mango for your help, I tried but this not worked for me. I found  where was the problem, actually when i got this error-> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it? so i used following command=>1. sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock  2.sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock . so due to this my system was broken. so i reinstalled the ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) and xrdp on it. Now it working and this error is gone..!  Thanks Ones again

Comment: @firefly Anytime. Feel free to up-vote if you think this was a good answer.